# Derivative on index symbols in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to do symbolical calculations (derivatives mostly) on time-indexed variables using sympy.
Using indexed symbols like r[t] below produces an error:

```
from sympy import *
t = Idx('t',10)
r = IndexedBase('r')

diff(r[t],r[t])
diff(r,r)

ValueError: 
Can't differentiate wrt the variable: r[t], 1
```

Could the reason be that something went wrong here:

```
In [15]: r[t].indices
Out[15]: (t,)
```

The comma after the index t looks suspicious to me, but I have no idea what went wrong.

Does anyone know how to do this in sympy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can differentiate wrt symbols, functions and derivatives. Will this work:

```
>>> t = Idx('t',10)
>>> r=Function('r')
>>> r(t).diff(r(t))
1
>>> var('t')
t
>>> r(t).diff(t)
Derivative(r(t), t)
```